# Problem with integral. Wrong answer?

Tags: calculus

Hello so I solved the integral

$$\int\frac{x}{\pi x+2}dx$$

by writing it as $\frac{1}{\pi}\int\frac{x+2-2}{x+2}dx$
and then like this:

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\int1dx - 2\int\frac{1}{x+2}dx\right)$$

and my answer was $\frac{x}{\pi}-\frac{2}{\pi}ln|x+2|+C$

but the solution manual got the answer:

$$\frac{x}{\pi} -\frac{2}{\pi^2}\,\ln|\pi x+2|+C$$

and I cannot figure out why

Comment: There is a difference between $\frac{x}{\pi x+2}$ and $\frac1{\pi}\frac{x}{x+2}$

Comment: Or more to the point, $\pi x+2\ne \pi(x+2)$.

Comment: You are right! :o

Comment: So when programming, @JavaProgrammer, check parentheses!  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int \frac{x}{\pi x +2}dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int \frac{x}{x+2/\pi}dx$